# E40: Can't open errorfile C:\DOCUME~1\[...] on windows

Tags: python, windows, vim, pylint

I'm trying to use `pylint.vim` on windows.

I have https://github.com/orenhe/pylint.vim version in `C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\compiler` direcory. I added:

```
autocmd FileType python compiler pylint
```

To `C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc` file, also pylint is recognized in my system as command.

But when I'm saving python source code, instead of pylint output I'm getting:

```
"file.py" 199L, 5876C written
Error detecded while processing function Pylint:
line 11:
E40: Can't open errorfile C:\DOCUME~1\xxx\LOCALS~1\Temp\VIeAA.tmp
```

How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT:**
As lunaryorn suggested I did try with syntastic. But I got similar issue, also find thread about it: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/29 But still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Try [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic)?

Comment: Works fine on linux. But on windows with gvim I get the same issue - E40: Can't open errorfile `C:\DOCUME~1\[...]\VIe5e.tmp`.

Comment: Sorry to hear.  It's probably an issue with the Windows shell syntax in the Pylint checker.  Report this issue to the syntastic developers.